# Pick item based on percentage

Tags: java, probability

I'm creating a plugin and I'm struggling to figure out how to pick a winner based on their percentage, using a `HashMap`.

In my plugin, each player deposits an item, and, based on the item's worth, they receive a percentage back. I'm trying to pick a winner based on probability. Now there are **multiple** users that are depositing items, which means the number could be a `Double`.

Is there any way that I could calculate this?

```
package com.test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

static HashMap<String, Double> JackpotEntrys = new HashMap<String, Double>();
static HashMap<String, Double> JackpotPCE = new HashMap<String, Double>();
static HashMap<String, Double> Stage1JPE = new HashMap<String, Double>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JackpotEntrys.put("mrgreen33gamer", 155.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("XeneonHD", 270.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("BadBoyBaldSpot", 760.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("Kingcreeper6", 455.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("Kingcreeper5", 50.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("Kingcreeper4", 100.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("Kingcreeper3", 20.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("Kingcreeper2", 15.000);
    JackpotEntrys.put("Kingcreeper1", 5.000);

    Set<String> PCES1 = JackpotEntrys.keySet();
    for (Iterator<String> i = PCES1.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
        String key = (String) i.next();
        Double value = (Double) JackpotEntrys.get(key);



    }

    JPValue();
    PCE_JPE_Pick();

}

public static void JPValue(){
    Collection<Double> values = JackpotEntrys.values();

    int Total = 0;
    for (Double value : values) {
        Total += value;
    }
    System.out.println("Jackpot was totalled at: " + Total);
}

public static void PCE_JPE_Pick(){

    System.out.println("========== NEW LINE ==============");

    Set<String> PCES1 = JackpotEntrys.keySet();
    for (Iterator<String> i = PCES1.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
        String key = (String) i.next();
        Double value = (Double) JackpotEntrys.get(key);


        double finalPE = value / 1000;

        JackpotPCE.put(key, finalPE);
    }

    Set<String> PCES2 = JackpotPCE.keySet();
    for(Iterator<String> i2 = PCES2.iterator(); i2.hasNext(); ){
        String key = (String) i2.next();
        Double value = (Double) JackpotPCE.get(key);
        System.out.println(key + " has a probability of DOUBLE: " + value);
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    double randomValue = 0 + (1 - 0) * r.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(randomValue);

}

public static double probabilityCal(double PlayerDepot) {

    Collection<Double> values = JackpotEntrys.values();
    int Total = 0;
    for (Double value : values) {
        Total += value;
    }

    double percentage = (double) ((PlayerDepot * 100) / Total);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    double finalPercentage = Double.parseDouble(df.format(percentage));
    return finalPercentage;
}
}
```

Another thing: If I was trying to pick a winner that had 33 percent each, how would I pick that player?

Comment: Your task is not clear. Try a better description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an algorithm, I can help. So say you have three percentage values 25%, 25%, and 50%. What you have to do is convert these into consecutive ranges between 0 and 1 so the first becomes the range 0 to 0.25, the second becomes the range 0.25 to 0.5, the third becomes the range 0.5 to 1. Generate a random double between 0 and 1 and whichever range your random number falls in, is the winner.

Comment: Hey dude, I did what you said and all, but how will I generate a very low double like: 

Kingcreeper1 has a probability of DOUBLE: 0.005

Comment: I'm not to good in Java but from what I know, the double generator in the Random class is pretty precise

Comment: Dude. Let's just say I have 3 players with a percent of 33%, convert the decimal, .33. How would i pick a winner? I mean what if people have 0.005. How would I know that person won? Do I subtract all the values from that one?

Comment: My idea was to assign a range for each player, with a max and min. So to generate ranges, loop through all the players. Start with the first min as 0 and the first max as .33 then loop through the rest of the players. The current player min will be the previous max, the current max will be the current min plus the percentage, in this case .33. Repeat. Does that make sense? The ranges for this case will be (0,.33) (.33,.66) (.66, 1.0) You can just make the last range max = 1 because it will be a negligible difference.

Comment: Do you have a Skype or Gmail? We can talk over on whatever.

Comment: My email is on my profile page. Contact me and I will see what I can do to walk you through this :)

Comment: The basic problem is "sampling from a discrete distribution" and a lot of approaches are mentioned in this Wikipedia article [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling#Finite_discrete_distributions). One of the fastest and most popular approaches: the Alias-method.

Comment: @sascha this looks like what I did. Or is there a better solution?